# Superglobal GET using PHP

Tags: php, html, superglobals

I am new to php and I couldn't find the answer on stack. I am experimenting and trying to figure out how I can use the superglobal GET to display an image and also change the *count depending on how the user modifies it in the URL.

I would like to change the Beach image *count* times.

So the URL would look something like:
**website.com/table?beach_image=2&count=4**

and would display the beach image #2, 4 times:
[bathing suit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7pVG.png)

```
<?php
$beach = ['sunglasses.jpg','suncreen.jpg','bathing-suit.jpg','hat.jpg'];
$count = 1;

    $beach_image = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"beach_image");
?>
```

for my html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Beach Image</th>
        <th>Beach</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>Sunglasses</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Sunscreen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Bathing Suit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Hat</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div>
    <img src="images/<?= $beach[$beach_image]?>">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below

```
<?php
$beach = ['sunglasses.jpg','suncreen.jpg','bathing-suit.jpg','hat.jpg'];
$keysArr = array_fill(0,count($beach),0);//array_combine(array_keys($beach),array_fill(0,count($beach),0)); 

$beach_image = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"beach_image");
$count = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"count");
$keysArr[$beach_image] = $count;
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Beach Image</th>
        <th>Beach</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $keysArr[0] ;?></td>
        <td>Sunglasses</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $keysArr[1] ;?></td>
        <td>Sunscreen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $keysArr[2] ;?></td>
        <td>Bathing Suit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $keysArr[3] ;?></td>
        <td>Hat</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div>
    <?php for($i=1;$i=$count;$i++){?>
        <img src="images/<?= $beach[$beach_image]?>">
    <?php }?>
</div>
```